# Can I solve for a radix?

Tags: number-systems

If I know that

$$100=(5\text{A})_{18}=(6\text{A})_{15}$$

Can I solve for the (presumably non-integer) radix $r$ that satisfies the following?

$$100=(7\text{A})_r$$

Comment: Expand $(7A)_r = 7r+10$.

Comment: While that equation can be solved, non-integer radices don't make much sense when talking about integers because you cannot express every natural number with them.